# How to search back in directory tree on GNU/Linux for a file

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, gnu

I have few repositories and each have config.php file that contain information about database like password. I have script that connect to database using stuff from that file and need to search back in directory tree so I can call it in every nested directory.

```
[ -e config.php ] && $(php -r 'require("config.php"); echo "mysql -u".$config["db_user"] . " -p".$config["db_pass"] . " " . $config["db_name"];')
```

What is easiest way to search back in directory tree using Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chops off a directory from the end of `PWD` until it becomes empty. Some care may need to be taken in the presence of links.

```
S="${PWD}"
while [ -n "${S}" ]
do
    [ -e "config.php" ] && ls $S/
    S=${S%/*}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

'find topdir/ -type f -iname "config.php"' where 'topdir' is the uppermost directory where your config scripts reside. The depending on your requirements you may want to process the 'config.php' files in one go using

'find topdir/ -type f -iname "config.php" -print0 | xargs -0 yourscript'

or one by one
'find topdir/ -type f -iname "config.php" -exec yourscript {} \;'

Comment: I was thinking more about `pwd` split by `/` and do test for config.php. the script you write will search every inner directory inside topdir/ I want to search back to root. and I don't know where my config.php reside I want to search for it like find by reversed.

Comment: The following bash script will iteratively chop off the last directory from `$PWD`. Inside the loop instead of echoing `$S` you can test for the existance of `config.php` S="${PWD}";

while [ -n "${S}" ] ;
do
    echo $S ;
    S=${S%/*} ;
done

Comment: I use this `S="${PWD}"; while [ -n "${S}" ] ; do [ -e "$S/config.php" ] && ls $S/; S=${S%/*} ; done` and it work put that as an answer and I accept it.